# How to get the height of an element and use it in a function?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm trying to use jquery to determine the height of an element and then determine if a user has scrolled that distance. The application is that I have a header followed by a navbar. As the user scrolls down the page the header will disappear and the navbar will stay fixed to the top of the screen. I have this working using the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
    jQuery("#top-header").hide(300);
} else {
    jQuery("#top-header").show(300);
}
```

});

But I want to use media queries to change the height of #top-header based on screen size instead of leaving it the same. So what I'd like to do is determine the height of #top-header (or some element within it) and then use that value in the function to hide it. I know I can use some form of $('#top-header).height but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into the function.

Thanks,
CJ

Comment: not able to understand your question! If height of element is what you desire, then `var result = $("#myDiv").height();` will work.

Comment: @san A I understand that using the .height code is what I want, but I can't figure out how to replace the '100' in my function with this. Simply putting `$("#top-header").height()` in place of the 100 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of predefined height, use the jQuery [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) element function.

```
var header = $("#top-header");

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > header.height()) {
    header.hide(300);
  } else {
    header.show(300);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I see what this is supposed to do, but it doesn't work. If I replace my code within the <script>tags with this nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('document').ready(function(){    
   $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     var header = $("#top-header").height();

     if(scroll > header){
        header.hide(300);
     }else{
        header.show(300);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually got it to work. I think the problems with implementing either of the answers provided is the syntax in which I was trying to do it within - a joomla page. I'll post below what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers provided above I was able to tweak my original code to get it to work as intended. Here's what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > (jQuery("#top-header").height())) {
    jQuery("#top-header").hide(300);
} else {
    jQuery("#top-header").show(300);
}
});
</script>
```

Bear in mind this is within a joomla page that has jquery loaded by default.